# Inconsistent Rails Test Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The first couple times I run rspec spec, I receive failures and if I run it again and thereafter, it passes. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

This appears to be related to uniqueness code to prevent adding a record with a name that has already been. Below is the test that consistently fails the first time:

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).case_insensitive.with_message(/has already been taken. Please use a different name./) }
```

The full repo can be found here: https://github.com/melissajstudent/koth

Answer (score 0):

You are right in thinking that the uniquess is a good indicator of what’s happening. Likely your test database has some remaining records from the last time you ran the tests and is trying to creat records with the same factories.

To that end, there are a few ways to clean your database in between runs of your test suites. Sometimes it’s helpful just to run `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare` Before running your test suite. In other cases you can implement some more robust database cleaning throughout your run with the database cleaner gem: https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner