# Rails tests are inconsistent in their results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, testing

I read this similar post. [Inconsistent Rails Test Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477526/inconsistent-rails-test-results).
It only has one response and it doesn't help me.

I've been following along with this new book called Agile Web Development with Rails 6.  And the author runs these tests and they don't work for me.

Here's what I did.

I created a new rails project using `new rails test` and then ran `rails generate scaffold Product title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal`.  This is the command that the author uses.
I then run `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` and then am ready to run `rails test`.

After doing that I get this response in the console.
`7 runs, 5 assertions, 0 failures, 3 errors, 0 skips`

Here are the errors.

```
Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActionView::Template::Error: Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename - (C:/Users/Client/Desktop/Ruby on Rails/tests/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v4.0.0/-T/-TZMQrMJrqe1bey8hRhmqKVmncCU8rFfTfOziZyMSMQ.cache.74410620.20908.613522, C:/Users/Client/Desktop/Ruby on Rails/tests/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v4.0.0/-T/-TZMQrMJrqe1bey8hRhmqKVmncCU8rFfTfOziZyMSMQ.cache)
```

```
Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_show_product:
ActionView::Template::Error: Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename - (C:/Users/Client/Desktop/Ruby on Rails/tests/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v4.0.0/HM/HMwQEAOlQlZbn_VGqaBmumzU5MudrUMOA7mZ9lf-I3U.cache.73876560.20908.130802, C:/Users/Client/Desktop/Ruby on Rails/tests/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v4.0.0/HM/HMwQEAOlQlZbn_VGqaBmumzU5MudrUMOA7mZ9lf-I3U.cache)
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:27:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
```

```
Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_product:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked
    app/controllers/products_controller.rb:57:in `destroy'
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:42:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
```

The inconsistency is that my results vary, here are some of them

`7 runs, 7 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors, 0 skips`

`7 runs, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 4 errors, 0 skips`

`7 runs, 8 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips`

And once I had 0 failures and 0 errors. I am absolutely new to Ruby on Rails so any help is appreciated.
Also, I have tried running `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare` which I read in the post I linked at the top.  That didn't help me.

**Edit**: I didn't realize it was important, but my project is actually named tests, not test.  So the conflict with the test keyword is not happening.  Also, I set up this "test" project after another project named "depot" was initially failing the tests.

My rails version: 6.0.3.2

My Ruby version: 2.6.6p146

Here are the tests for the permission denied errors.
This is excerpted from this file, `test\controllers\products_controller_test.rb`

```
test "should get index" do
    get products_url
    assert_response :success
end

test "should show product" do
  get product_url(@product)
  assert_response :success
end
```

My gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.6'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

My Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby
  revision: 1027509079176fcc4088dcc7638101cde617cf16
  branch: add-gemspec
  specs:
    sqlite3 (1.3.13.20180326210955)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.2)
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      actionview (= 6.0.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.2)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.0.3.2)
      actionview (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.8)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.2)
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
    activerecord (6.0.3.2)
      activemodel (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
    activestorage (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.2)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (6.0.3.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.4.6)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.33.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.5)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.6)
    crass (1.0.6)
    erubi (1.9.0)
    ffi (1.13.1-x64-mingw32)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.8.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.10.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    loofah (2.6.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mimemagic (0.3.5)
    mini_mime (1.0.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.14.1)
    msgpack (1.3.3-x64-mingw32)
    nio4r (2.5.2)
    nokogiri (1.10.9-x64-mingw32)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    public_suffix (4.0.5)
    puma (4.3.5)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-proxy (0.6.5)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.0.3.2)
      actioncable (= 6.0.3.2)
      actionmailbox (= 6.0.3.2)
      actionmailer (= 6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      actiontext (= 6.0.3.2)
      actionview (= 6.0.3.2)
      activejob (= 6.0.3.2)
      activemodel (= 6.0.3.2)
      activerecord (= 6.0.3.2)
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 6.0.3.2)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.0.3.2)
      actionpack (= 6.0.3.2)
      activesupport (= 6.0.3.2)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.20.3, < 2.0)
    rake (13.0.1)
    regexp_parser (1.7.1)
    rubyzip (2.3.0)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.4.0-x64-mingw32)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (1.0.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.7)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2020.1)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    web-console (4.0.3)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (4.4.1)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webpacker (4.2.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 4.2)
    websocket-driver (0.7.2)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.3.0)

PLATFORMS
  x64-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.4.2)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 2.15)
  jbuilder (~> 2.7)
  puma (~> 4.1)
  rails (~> 6.0.3, >= 6.0.3.1)
  sass-rails (>= 6)
  selenium-webdriver
  sqlite3!
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)
  webdrivers
  webpacker (~> 4.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.6p146

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.2
```

Comment: I assume it was `rails new test` not `new rails test`. What version of Rails? Newer versions reserve "test". And can we see the tests? To the `permission denied` errors, did you switch users during this process? `rails tmp:clear` might help.

Comment: I didn't switch users.  By switch users I assume you mean the user accounts on my windows OS.  I never switch users.

Comment: Ahh, Windows. Windows has mandatory file locking for open files which can look like permission errors and SQLite database locks. Running Rails on Windows takes more work. Try following the [Install Ruby On Rails on
Windows 10](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10) guide and [Installing and troubleshooting Ruby on Rails (SQLite3 Windows 10 fix)](https://medium.com/@declancronje/installing-and-troubleshooting-ruby-on-rails-sqlite3-windows-10-fix-87c8886d03b).

Comment: Okay, thanks for that.  I will look into those links.

Comment: I'm having some trouble following the medium article.  The author says to replace this line inside the gemfile, `gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'` his example doesn't have the version number but mine does.  He says to replace it with, `gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"` and then run `bundle install`.  Everything seems fine after that but when I run rails server and head to localhost:3000, I am presented with this error in the browser. Puma caught this error: Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? ...

Comment: Here is the rest of the top part of the error, it may be crucial.  Missing a gem it depends on? can't activate sqlite3 (~> 1.4), already activated sqlite3-1.3.13.20180326210955. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (LoadError)
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'

Comment: I would need to see your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to help out.

Comment: I will add it to my original question.

Comment: I don't think you're having the SQLite problem that alternative version of the sqlite gem will fix. I would suggest trying the advice from the other one about using Windows Subsystem for Linux. I've only tried Rails on Windows once; we wound up getting a Mac. I've tagged your question with "windows", hopefully that will get it the proper attention. I can give it a shot in my Windows 10 machine. How did you install Ruby?

Comment: I will try that first link out to try the linux solution.  I believe I used https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and click the Ruby+Devkit 2.6.601 (x64).

Comment: I think I'm on the right track now.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Rails do not allow you to make an application called "test" because it can clash with existing modules and classes.

```
$ rails new test
Invalid application name test. Please give a name which does not match one of the reserved rails words: application, destroy, plugin, runner, test
```

[This was added 11 years ago](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d4e008fd0f9ebac3383a0c3ac093de68db9e2e66) so your copy of Rails might be very out of date. Upgrade Rails and try a different name like `test.rails`. It Works For Me™.

Comment: My bad, my project is actually called "tests", I didn't realize it was an important distinction.  My rails version is 6.0.3.2 and ruby version is 2.6.6p146.

Comment: @HolyMoeller `rails new tests` works for me. It looks like a permissions problem in your tmp directory. Try clearing your cache: `rails tmp:clear`. And please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62613829/edit) with the correct information so others can help.

Comment: Running `rails tmp:clear` didn't help, my `rails test` is still producing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Having received the same error while running 'rails test' on Windows, try running only one test at a time. Worked for me. When running more than one test, it gives the error you show. That's not a long term solution but maybe it helps you troubleshoot.